# How to keep a formula field updated everyday to send email alerts?

Tags: formula-field

I have a requirement that updates the number of working days in a formula Field based on another date field. I need to keep this field updated everyday and send email alerts based on specific number of business days. I have created the formula field that calculates the number of business days.

How do I keep this formula field updated everyday?

Comment: You seem to have a misconception as to how formula fields work.  

Formula fields are just that, formulas. Salesforce stores the formula itself in their database, and when you (or anyone else, or any _thing_ else) query for the field, the formula is evaluated and a value returned _for that point in time_.  

If you wanted to change the definition of a formula field (outside of doing it through Salesforce's web UI), you would need to use the Metadata API. I would not recommend this.

Comment: To me, this sounds like an XY-problem, where you're asking about how to make the solution (the Y in XY-problem) you've come up with (programatically changing a formula field every day) work instead of asking how to solve the overall problem (the X in the XY-problem). Please give us more details about the problem you're trying to solve, and avoid focusing on a single approach to solving the problem in your question. You can [edit] your question to include additional details.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to create a Schedulable class, that you would schedule to run at a specific time daily.

When you create your record and you fill in the DateFieldA, FormulaA gets populated automatically with the number of days.

Say, number of days = 5.
FormulaA = 5
So, you have to send an email for 5 days.

Create a new field called 'EmailSent'. It would be read only field.

Create a Schedulable class.
Query FormulaA and EmailSent.

```
If (EmailSent < FormulaA) {
    //send email
    //update EmailSent to [value of EmailSent previously queried] + 1
    //so the counter (EmailSent) would be incremented daily until the number of emails required have been sent 
}
else{
    //meaning number of emails required have already been sent [number of days have already be lapsed]
    //do not do anything here. Else part not needed.
}
```

**Note #1:**

If you are using TODAY()/NOW()/etc in your formula, solution will not work.
It will recalculate the number of days [formulaA] everytime the record is updated with new value for EmailSent field.

Then instead of formula field, use TextFieldA or NumberA to keep the number of days.

Update this field via a field update action on a workflow rule.

WF Rule condition would be 'when DateFieldA is changed'.

**Note #2:**

Also, if you are dealing with bulk data, you may consider using a schedulable batch.
Class would be:

```
public class ClassA implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Scheduable
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you need code example, someone posted a question with code snippet where they used `implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable` to send email notification. It may help. 
[Link to question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199376/invoking-batch-class-with-different-query-sets)